# Customize "Downloading" message in Inno Download Plugin

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, inno-download-plugin

Is there any way to change the message in downloading page?

At the place of *"Downloading..."* I want to include the file name like *"Downloading exe"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change Inno Download Plugin messages, use `IDP_xxx` custom messages.

Particularly for the *"Downloading..."* message, change the `IDP_Downloading`:

```
[CustomMessages]
IDP_Downloading=Downloading...
```

For other messages, look for `{cm:` string in the `idp.iss`.

Comment: Note that some of the default message files have incomplete translations. I put some updated files on the IDP bitbucket repository in the Issues section but you have to adjust the language identifiers.